# How to add characters to input when onBlur fires

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have an input field where I enter numbers

When the onBlur fires, I need to add a % symbol to my numbers
i have this function

```
const onBlurValue = (day_index, value) => {
   const newBreakDownMonths = [...breakDownMonths];
   const day = newBreakDownMonths[nowMonth].break_down_days[day_index];
   if(value == "") {
      day.value = 0;
   } else {
      day.value = value;
   }
   setChangedDay(day);
}
```

I’ll tell you briefly what it does. When onBlur is triggered, if there is nothing in the input field, then there will be 0, if we enter numbers, it will save the numbers.

How to add % character to numbers when onBlur fires?
I have custom an input field that accepts events and a value -

```
<Input
  inputProps={{
    value: day.value,
    type: "number",
    step: "0.1",
    onKeyDown: (e) => detectKeyDown(e, day),
    onChange: (e) => onChangeValue(index, e.target.value),
    onFocus: (e) => onFocusValue(index, e.target.value),
    onBlur: (e) => onBlurValue(index, e.target.value),
    style: {
      marginTop: 0,
    },
  }}
/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Hook to remember the value, and append `%` in the `onBlur` callback

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <input
              type='text'
              value={value}
              onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
              onBlur={_ => setValue(value + ' %')}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I would do `setValue(value.replace(/\D/g,'') + ' %')` so it removes everything but numbers from the value, before applying the space and % sign again -  a user will type 10, then blur, then go back and change it to 100, which would result in `100 % %`